# selenium-webdriver error for just opening IE

Tags: cucumber, selenium-webdriver, irb

So, I am using -

```
gem 'watir-webdriver', '0.5.4'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.21.1'
```

and JRuby - 1.6.5

All I am trying to do is open IE. I have IE version 8.

```
>> require "rubygems"
=> true

?> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true

?> @b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError: Modal dialog present
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:64:in `request'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:62:in `request'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:92:in `create_session'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/ie/bridge.rb:40:in `initialize'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:35:in `for'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:63:in `for'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.5.8/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:35:in `initialize'
from (irb):5:in `evaluate'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:158:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:271:in `signal_status'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:154:in `eval_input'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:71:in `start'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `catch'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in `start'
from C:/jruby-1.6.5/bin/jirb:13:in `(root)'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `(root)'>>
```

IE webdriver gets opened, but above error comes.

When I use any other browser - firefox or chrome - they just open as they were supposed to open. It started happen just from this week. I mean I am using selenium-webdriver for years now and never had a problem opening IE or any browser. Error says there is a modal dialog box, but how can there be a modal dialog box when I just open IE, and I don't see any dialog when IE webdriver opens up. And if so, why other browsers don't complain?

I am assuming it might need to do with some windows or security updates that gets pushed on company laptop, but I just want to see if someone else have encountered this before and what was the solution?

Comment: Open a blank window in IE yourself, do you see a dialog or anything like that? Usually it indicates selenium detected something out of line in the 'natural' browser state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities I can think of. One is that you have the Windows Task Manager open when you're trying to execute your tests. There is a bug in previous versions of the IE driver that could improperly throw the UnexpectedAlertException if the Task Manager were open while running code with the IE driver.

The second option is a browser plugin that internally creates a dialog window, but keeps it hidden. There are a number of antivirus and other anti-malware plugins for IE that may cause the issue.

In either case, update to a [later version of IEDriverServer.exe](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=IEDriverServer_Win32_2.29.1.zip) to see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

okay, found a solution. It was anti-virus thingy. The issue was -  when you are running script with IE the McAfee site adviser modal window is sitting on top of IE browser so we can not get to IE browser to even open it. and it was specific to IE only because IE being 'default' and 'preferred' browser in my workplace.

McAfee supplied two dll files and copy-pasting them to some specific location solved the issue. Sorry, I used all of your minds in this question while it was not related to selenium but was mcafee issue. Closing the question.